# [Python Falcon]: gunicorn working in terminal but not in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, gunicorn

I am trying to run the falcon application in PyCharm so that I can run the debugger. I am able to start the falcon application from the command line, however I am not able to start it from PyCharm.

The project structure is the following:

```
FalconTutorial
  - service
    - __init__.py
    - app.py
```

Here is the code in app.py:

```
import json
import falcon

class Hello:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        doc = {"message": 'Hello!'}
        resp.body = json.dumps(doc, ensure_ascii=False)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

application = falcon.API()
application.add_route('/hello', Hello())
```

For starting the application from command-line, I go to the FalconTutorial directory and run the following:

```
source /path-to-pyenv/bin/activate && gunicorn --reload 'service.app'
```

The server starts up fine. However, when I try the same thing with PyCharm, it is not working.

I'm using the following in PyCharm:

```
Script Path: /path-to-pyenv/bin/gunicorn
Parameters: --reload 'service.app'
Python interpreter: /path-to-pyenv/bin/python
Working Directory: /Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/FalconTutorial
```

I get this error:
    ImportError: No module named "'service"

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed looking at the error message closely (it has extra ' (single quote) inside the quotes).

Although adding single quote works in terminal, it does not work in PyCharm. Either remove the single quote or use the double quote instead. Changing the following worked:

```
Parameters: --reload service.app
```